# newcommand with optional superscript

Tags: macros, superscripts

In my thesis i need to use quite often the partial differential fraction like

```
\frac{\partial^\alpha x}{\partial y^\alpha }}
```

I therefore defined the command

```
\newcommand{\partialfrac}[3][]{\frac{\partial^ #1 #2}{\partial #3 ^ #1}}
```

That should be equal to the first one using

```
\partialfrac[\alpha]{x}{y}
```

That works if I define the optional #1 input. I would like to be able to skip the superscript if i want to (usually ^1 is not written...) but if I omit the optional input i receive an error. Is there a way to tell latex to "skip" the superscript somehow?

Thankyou

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An expandable test would be:

```
\ifx\\#1\\%
  % #1 is empty
\else
  % #1 is not empty
\fi
```

Also `^#1` fails if `#1` consists of several tokens. This is fixed by `^{#1}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\partialfrac}[3][]{%
  \frac{%
    \partial \ifx\\#1\\\else^{#1}\fi #2%
  }{%
    \partial #3 \ifx\\#1\\\else^{#1}\fi
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\[
  \partialfrac{a}{b} = \partialfrac[\alpha]{x}{y}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 4):

I think there is still room for an [`xparse`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse)-based version. Thanks to `\IfNoValueTF` test, it is possible to check whether the optional first argument is present:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\partialfrac}{o m m}{%
\IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
 \frac{\partial #2}{\partial #3}%
}{%
 \frac{\partial^{#1}#2}{\partial #3^{#1}}%
}%
}

\begin{document}
\[
  \partialfrac{a}{b} = \partialfrac[\alpha]{x}{y}
\]
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

use `etoolbox` to test for optional argument and act accordingly.

```
\newcommand{\partialfrac}[3][]{\frac{\partial\ifblank{#1}{}{^ #1} #2}
      {\partial #3 \ifblank{#1}{}{^ #1}}}
```

(untested)

Answer (score 1):

Without a package, you can do it thus:

```
\newcommand{\partialfrac}[3][]{%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax\let\mysscript\relax\else\def\mysscript{^{#1}}\fi%
  \frac{\partial\mysscript #2}{\partial #3\mysscript}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry I opened this question: i tried for 1 hour before opening it and then found the solution 2 minutes after....

This

```
\newcommand{\partialfrac}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1}#2}{\partial#3^{#1}}}
```

works as intended.

Thank you very much

Comment: You will note that a slight horizontal space is introduces with the syntax `^{}`, which may not be what you actually wish, when the argument is blank.

Comment: You are right... I will look for one of yours solution.